# What is the rationale behind minus reputation for downvoting answers?

Tags: discussion, reputation, downvotes

IMHO downvoting less constructive answers sometimes contributes just as much to the quality of this site as upvoting the best ones. Especially downvoting [fairly popular answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73663/terminating-a-python-script/73680#73680) that are still not really good practice. So what is the reasoning behind giving the voter minus reputation score for downvotes on answers?

Comment: To be clear, you're referring to the penalty incurred on the *voter*, right?

Comment: I agree with your first sentence. Even more strongly than you do. ;)

Comment: @BoltClock Yes.

Comment: As constructive as down-voting non-constructive answers is, having free voting would most likely lead to more tactical down-voting, more revenge-votes, and in general non-constructive voting.